# WebStorm is ignoring some files contained in project folder

Tags: webstorm

from time to time WebStorm ignores some files that are inside project folder when I am trying to search for them through <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> (search file function).

Here is picture:
[image]

I am trying to search file `edit-driver-license.html`. As you can see, this file is really there so WebStorm should find it.

When I go to native windows file explorer and move the file into another folder and then back, WebStorm refreshes project structure and find the file. So problem solved.

But when I restart WebStorm, everything will be like before and the file will not be able to be found...

Is there any solution for this? Like, is there some ignore file list, or is this just a bug? This is not the first time it happened. I had same issues earlier, but I fixed it by restarting WebStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me too from time to time, and it's a caching problem.

Usually it gets fixed when I go to **File -> Invalidade Cache/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart**

**Attention:** Please read the warning before invalidating the cache: it'll also clean your Local History.

Try it, should work.

Comment: This will cause the IDE to start re-indexing all your project files, so it may take a while after the restart until you can see the problem gone.

Comment: yep this solved the problem. But I don't like this solution, because it deletes all caches including local GIT versions of files. So local history of files is empty now. Such a shame, because I am using it from time to time. Nevermind, thanks for your fast reply

Comment: Yeah it'll remove your local history as well as stated in the dialog box. I updated the answer with that information that I forgot to include.

Comment: As for deleting local git versioning, I don't think it does, since those files are controlled by the `.git` directory and not the `.idea`.

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský Small clarification: *"including local GIT versions of files"* It's not "local git versions" -- Local History is own mini-VCS (lets call it this way) that has no relation to any VCS and works without it. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/local-history.html

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for clarfication. I didn't know how to call it, But you get the point and it's important.